# Plotting rasters with a layer of points and extracting the pixel values at that point using R

Tags: r, raster, lattice

I am attempting to plot NDVI raster layers and add a layer of point. I then want to extract the pixel values at those points however I keep getting an error when trying to add the layer of points.

#plot NDVI

> levelplot(stack(NDVI), scales=list(draw=FALSE), colorkey=FALSE, par.settings=mapTheme) + layer(sp.points(test_pts,pch=13, col=69, bg='red', cex=10, lwd=10, force=TRUE))
> Error:
> ! Can't create layer without a geom.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

#extract pixel values at point coord

NDVI_points <- lapply(NDVI, FUN=function (NDVI) {extract(NDVI, test_pts, method='simple', df=TRUE)})
Error in UseMethod("extract") :
no applicable method for 'extract' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster', 'BasicRaster')"Error in `extract()`:
! Arguments in `...` must be used.
✖ Problematic arguments:
• method = "simple"
• df = TRUE

Answer (score 0):

I realized the functions that I used were being pulled from the wrong library.

My code changed to:

#plot NDVI
levelplot(stack(NDVI), scales=list(draw=FALSE), colorkey=FALSE, par.settings=mapTheme) +
**latticeExtra::layer**(sp.points(test_pts,pch=13, col=69, bg='red', cex=2, lwd=2, force=TRUE))

#extract pixel values at point coord
NDVI_points <- lapply(NDVI, FUN=function (NDVI) {**raster::extract**(NDVI, test_pts, method='simple', df=TRUE)})
NDVI_points